# How can I get the program to repeat without having the user have to close out of the shell?

Tags: python, shell, random, numbers, generator

I am having trouble finding a way to get the user to repeat the code without having to exit out the shell. This is what I have so far.

```
import random
randomNum = random.randint(1, 10)
start = True
answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#The code cant be both less than and greater than. The or function allows this 
while (answer > randomNum) or (answer < randomNum):
    if (answer == randomNum + 1):
        print "Super Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#First one
    elif (answer == randomNum + 2):
        print "Pretty Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Second one
    elif (answer == randomNum + 3):
        print "Fairly Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Third one
    elif (answer == randomNum + 4):
        print "Not Really Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Fourth one
    elif (answer == randomNum + 5):
        print "Far"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Fifth one
    elif (answer == randomNum - 5):
        print "Far"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Sixth one
    elif (answer == randomNum - 4):
        print "Not Really Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Seventh one
    elif (answer == randomNum - 3):
        print "Fairly Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Eighth one
    elif (answer == randomNum - 2):
        print "Pretty Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Nineth one
    elif (answer == randomNum - 1):
        print "Super Close"
        answer = int(raw_input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
#Tenth one
else:
    print "Good Job!"
    print randomNum
    if (start == True):
        answerAgain = raw_input("Do you want to restart this program ? ")
        if answerAgain == ("Yes", "yes", "ya", "Ya", "Okay", "Sure", "Si", "Start"):
        #Empty space because I don't know what to put in here.

        else:
            print "See ya next time!"
```

I would like to know how to get all of this code to apply to one variable or to repeat without me having to write it 50 times.

Comment: wrap the if statements into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put code in `while` loop to repeat it.

```
start = True

while start:

    # code

    if answerAgain.lower() in ('no', 'niet', 'bye'):
        start = False
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend enclosing the whole thing in a while loop.

```
start = True
while start == True:
    """your code here"""
    answerAgain = raw_input("Do you want to restart this program ? ")
        if answerAgain == ("Yes", "yes", "ya", "Ya", "Okay", "Sure", "Si", "Start"):
            start = True
        else:
            start = False
```

That way your entire code will run again if start == True.

I would also recommend that you use a list for your responses.

```
responses = ["Super Close", "Pretty Close", "Fairly Close", "Not Really Close", "Far"]
```

That way you can map to the appropriate response using the difference:

```
print responses[abs(answer - randomNum) - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use the absolute value between the number the user provides and your random number, you only have to document half as many cases (i.e. -1 and +1 get treated the same).
2. Rather than asking for their new answer in after each case, move this code to the top of the main loop since it's requests at the start of the program and following all 'wrong' answers.
3. For usage, you'll probably want to convert all 'word' answers to lowercase, as case doesn't appear to matter in the case.
4. You can use `quit()` to cleanly exit the program.

So maybe like this:

```
import random

while(True):
    randomNum = random.randint(1, 10)
    answer = 0
    while abs(answer - randomNum) > 0:
        answer = int(input("Try to guess a random number between 1 and 10. "))
        if abs(answer - randomNum) == 1:
            print("Super Close")
        elif abs(answer - randomNum) == 2:
            print("Pretty Close")
        # the other cases ...

    # gets here if abs(answer - randonNum) == 0, i.e. they guessed right
    print("Good Job!", randomNum)
    answerAgain = input("Do you want to restart this program ? ")
    if answerAgain.lower() in ["yes", "ya", "y", "okay", "sure", "si", "start"]:
        pass
    else:
        print("See ya next time!")
        quit()
```